# Hibernate mapping, entity with many to many relationship table

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping, hibernate-mapping

I got a many to many relationship between two tables. I mapping this using the annotation @ManyToMany.

> Table1 --->   Relational Table ---> Table 2

Using hibernate i don't have to create any entity for the relationship table so I have.

> Entity 1(Table 1) ---> Entity 2(Table 2)

But my problem is that i have another table and i must do a relationship between this 3th table and the relation table between the previous and i don't have any entity for do the relation.

> Table 3 ---> Relational Table

I mean this 3th table got a foreign key with the relational table that i used before...

How can i accomplishment this? Sorry for my english

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

here is an example. 
Imagine we have Products and Categories 
You have 2 entities Product and Category

Using the hibernate code-first approach, the entities will be like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
public class Product implements Serializable {
private Long id;
....

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "categories_products",
joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "category_id",
referencedColumnName = "id"),
inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id",
referencedColumnName = "id"))
private Set<Category> categories;
...
```

And here is the code for the code

```
public class Category {
private Long id;
private String name;
...
}
```

By using the annotation @JoinTable a third table will be created with the following constraints. It will have category_id which will point to Categories id and product_id referring to Products id.